Is it better to use the ariaHidden property in JavaScript or the aria-hidden attribute?
Is there a difference between setting aria-hidden on an element in JavaScript using the ariaHidden property instead of the aria-hidden attribute?
Example:
myElement.ariaHidden = isOpen ? "false" : "true";

or...
myElement.setAttribute("aria-hidden", isOpen ? "false" : "true");

I haven't seen a lot of use of the former example, usually it's always the latter using the setAttribute() method. Is it just syntactic preference, or is there a performance consideration?

I don't see how it would affect performance aspect since property just reflects attribute.

There is a difference.  Some examples here

.setAttribute() on average is very slightly slower than directly setting it with ariaHidden=. I will state, the difference is so minuscule and will likely never make an impact.  I ran 10 million tests with the script I had attached, and the results were:
"Time per operation using ariaHidden property: 0.0003465200 ms"
"Time per operation using setAttribute: 0.0004629700 ms"
"Setting via setAttribute was 0.0001164500 ms slower per operation."



const element = document.getElementById('testElement');

    const iterations = 10_000_000;
    function testAriaHiddenProperty() {
        let start = performance.now();
        for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            element.ariaHidden = i % 2 === 0 ? false : true;
        }
        let end = performance.now();
        return (end - start) / iterations; 
    }

    function testSetAttribute() {
        let start = performance.now();
        for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            element.setAttribute('aria-hidden', i % 2 === 0 ? 'false' : 'true');
        }
        let end = performance.now();
        return (end - start) / iterations; 
    }

    const propertyTimePerOp = testAriaHiddenProperty();
    const attributeTimePerOp = testSetAttribute();

    console.log(`Time per operation using ariaHidden property: ${propertyTimePerOp.toFixed(10)} ms`);
    console.log(`Time per operation using setAttribute: ${attributeTimePerOp.toFixed(10)} ms`);

    const difference = attributeTimePerOp - propertyTimePerOp;
    if (difference > 0) {
        console.log(`Setting via setAttribute was ${difference.toFixed(10)} ms slower per operation.`);
    } else if (difference < 0) {
        console.log(`Setting via ariaHidden property was ${Math.abs(difference).toFixed(10)} ms slower per operation.`);
    } 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Performance Comparison</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="testElement" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: lightblue;">Test Element</div>
</body>
</html>




Thanks, that's very insightful about performance

@MattSmith No problem!  Keep in mind, functions such as setAttribute() will likely always be slower for a few reasons:

You have to call the function, which does more than set one value
The function might have checks unknown to you, testing for null values or the like.  So if you are ever interested in comparing other functions, you could simply default to setting it directly, with the = sign, or quickly modify the quick script I attached to perform tests of your own.  I'm glad I could help!

